# Using yodelling to express mocking

Tags: word-usage

In german, it is possible to use 'yodelling (jodeln)' to describe an orator's tone when he is mocking someone in a derisive manner.

Is this possible in english, too, or are there other, more suitable terms to express this?

> 'Sure, who doesn't need fourhundred pairs of shoes?' he yodelled.

Comment: Sound of Music.

Comment: _Chortled_ maybe?

Comment: I was going to suggest [*yocking*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yocking) but it already has another meaning. Yodel-Ay-Ee-Oooo!

Comment: I've never heard this expression used but I really think we should start, it is just perfect

Answer (score 15):

I think an English ear would interpret the yodelling literally, to comical effect.

A better translation might be something like "*sneered*" or "*scoffed*".

Answer (score 3):

I've only seen "yodelling" used to refer to a specific way of singing. Words I would use are "jeered" or "scoffed". You could also say "he remarked mockingly".

Answer (score 1):

If this use of "yodeling" means that the speaker's voice is varying in pitch, then a good parallel in English would be "[singsong](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/singsong) voice".  A common (though considered immature) form of mocking is to repeat the target's words as if you were singing a nursery rhyme.

You could replace "yodeled" with "said in a singsong voice", or even "jeered/sneered/scoffed in a singsong voice" for extra color (as per the other suggestions).

Answer (score 0):

I would understand what you mean, and I'm quite sure I've seen it in some pre-20th century English-language books. If I remember which ones, I'll post them. However, I agree with Atkins and Jorge that "jeered", "scoffed" or "sneered" would better capture your intent.